# ionic2: how to make Bottom sheet

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to make bottom sheet with some buttons in ionic2, all resources I found are examples in ionic1: this is an example:
 this is the link I want to do like it:
[enter link description here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/bottomSheet)

is is my html:

```
<ion-content no-padding no-margin>
<ion-list no-lines no-padding no-margin>
    <ion-list-header>
        Share Options
    </ion-list-header>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-grid>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col col-3 text-center>
                    <button ion-button clear icon-only>
                        <ion-icon name="md-copy" id="copyIcon"></ion-icon>
                    </button><br/>
                    <span class="optionName">Copy Link</span>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col col-3 text-center>
                    <button ion-button icon-only class="SMBtn" id="FBBtn">
                        <ion-icon name="logo-facebook" color="light" id="FBIcon"></ion-icon>
                    </button><br/>
                    <span class="optionName">Facebook</span>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col col-3 text-center>
                    <button ion-button icon-only class="SMBtn" id="twitterBtn">
                        <ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon>
                    </button><br/>
                    <span class="optionName">Twitter</span>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col col-3 text-center>
                    <button ion-button icon-only class="SMBtn" id="googleBtn">
                        <ion-icon name="logo-googleplus"></ion-icon>
                    </button><br/>
                    <span class="optionName">Google Plus</span>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col col-3 text-center>
                    <button ion-button icon-only class="SMBtn" id="whatsBtn">
                        <ion-icon name="logo-whatsapp" id="copyIcon"></ion-icon>
                    </button><br/>
                    <span class="optionName">Wahts Up</span>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col col-3 text-center>
                    <button ion-button icon-only class="SMBtn" id="tumblrBtn">
                        <ion-icon name="logo-tumblr"></ion-icon>
                    </button><br/>
                    <span class="optionName">Tumblr</span>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col col-3 text-center>
                    <button ion-button icon-only class="SMBtn" id="linkedBtn">
                        <ion-icon name="logo-linkedin"></ion-icon>
                    </button><br/>
                    <span class="optionName">Linked-in</span>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col col-3 text-center>
                    <button ion-button icon-only class="SMBtn" id="moreBtn">
                        <ion-icon name="ios-more"></ion-icon>
                    </button><br/>
                    <span class="optionName">More</span>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

I make it appear like a popover but I don't want that I want it to be like action sheet appear from bottom, anyone can help me in this issue?

Comment: This link might helpful https://github.com/InfomediaLtd/angular2-materialize

Comment: Check out [ActionSheetController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/action-sheet/ActionSheetController/)

Comment: have you got something like in angularjs material design?  I am also looking for the same.